# Commonly used notation for functionals

Tags: soft-question, notation

I'm studying Halmos' Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces as a precursor to functional analysis. If $V$ is a vector space and $V^*$ its dual, and if $x \in V$ and $y \in V^*$, the notation of the bilinear form resulting from the action of a functional on a vector is first specified as $y(x)$, but subsequently as $[x,y]$.

I read elsewhere that $[x,y]$ is an "old-fashioned" notation, but it closely resembles the bra-ket notation used in quantum mechanics. As far as I know, bilinear/multilinear forms are also used in general relativity. I just want to know what notation is used more widely in the modern context, so that I can adopt it as early as possible and become comfortable in using it.

Comment: $y(x)$ and $\langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: Read elsewhere?

Comment: @Qmechanic: On one of the math stackexchange questions, don't remember which though.